# Centered Footnotes

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, footnotes

I would like my footnotes to be centered but couldn't find any literature on this. Here is a MWE.

```
\documentclass[lettersize,14pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[symbol,perpage]{footmisc}
\makeatletter %makes the footnote mark bigger
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\textsuperscript{\large{\@thefnmark}}}}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\rule{\linewidth}{0pt}}
\DefineFNsymbols*{safestar}{{$*$}{\textdagger}{\textdaggerdbl}{\textsection}
{\textparagraph}{\textbardbl}{$**$}{\textdagger\textdagger}
{\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\textsection\textsection}
{\textparagraph\textparagraph}{\textbardbl\textbardbl}}
\setfnsymbol{safestar}
\begin{document}
This is a line of text.\footnote{This is a footnote that should be centered.}
\end{document}
```

I am compiling with LuaLaTeX but I don't think it should matter.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass[lettersize,14pt,twoside,openright]{memoir}
\usepackage[symbol,perpage]{footmisc}
\makeatletter %makes the footnote mark bigger
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\hbox{\textsuperscript{\large{\@thefnmark}}}}
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{\insert\footins{%
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{%
       \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}%
    \color@begingroup\centering
      \@makefntext{%
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}%
    \color@endgroup}}%

\makeatother
\renewcommand\footnoterule{\rule{\linewidth}{0pt}}
\DefineFNsymbols*{safestar}{{$*$}{\textdagger}{\textdaggerdbl}{\textsection}
{\textparagraph}{\textbardbl}{$**$}{\textdagger\textdagger}
{\textdaggerdbl\textdaggerdbl}{\textsection\textsection}
{\textparagraph\textparagraph}{\textbardbl\textbardbl}}
\setfnsymbol{safestar}
\begin{document}
This is a line of text.\footnote{This is a footnote that should be centered.}
\end{document}
```

It is easier to use a simple environment `myfootnote` because you have no footnoterule.

Comment: Is that footnote definition taken directly from the memoir class and you just added `\centering`?

Comment: it is taken from `latex.ltx` but yes, `\centering` is the only new command.

Comment: What is `latex.ltx` and for future cases how would one go about finding the exact code used for a command?

Comment: it is the main LaTeX file and you can find it by running `kpsewhich latex.ltx`

Comment: @Neo: The `latexdef` command-line tool is useful.

Comment: @Neo: See [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx) on CTAN.

Comment: @Werner: where is the sense to use an external location when it is _always_ present on your local TeX installation?

Comment: @Herbert: Two reasons: (1) It's easier (for me) to reference a CTAN mirror than to tell someone to search their TDS (since I'm unfamiliar with the differences across platforms and TeX distributions); CTAN = one universal link. (2) It is now accessible even if your are not on your local machine! You know, for those days when you're sunning [ShareLaTeX](http://sharelatex.com) from your local library...

Comment: @Werner: it is the same on _all_ platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the preamble:

`\newcommand{\cfootnote}[1]{\footnote{\centering #1}}`

Then just use the `\cfootnote` command instead. In fact you can still use both commands, and `\cfootnotes` will appear centered and regular `\footnotes` won't.

Comment: With this solution you have to do something with the footnote rule...